# JQuery cycle through table

Tags: jquery

I have a table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Music</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="http://www.domin.com/link1.mp3">link1</a></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="http://www.domin.com/link2.mp3">link2</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="http://www.domin.com/link3.mp3">link3</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I also have two buttons, `next` and `prev`:

```
<button id="prev">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

I want every time click on next or prev buttons set class `play` to active row and get `play` mp3 url and set to jplayer by this function:

```
$('.play')(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');  
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: url
    }).jPlayer("play");
    return false;  
});
```

Comment: You question is a little unclear, what issue are you having?

Comment: @Macb i want something like this site http://mulesic.com/.   i have list of mp3 link and a jplayer and i used jquery to play each link when user click on them , my issue is i dont know how create a functionality let users to play next and prev mp3 link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added the class `play` to one of the `a` 
in the table. `Next` starts with the first row. `Prev` starts with the last row.
Then then move thorough the rows and loop if they get to the top/bottom.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ap3vmq97/)

```
$('#next').click(function () {
    if ($('table td a.play').length > 0 && $('table td a.play').parents('tr').next().length > 0) {
        $('table td a.play').removeClass('play').parents('tr').next().find('a').addClass('play');
    } else {
        $('table td a.play').removeClass('play');
        $('table td').first().find('a').addClass('play');
    }
});

$('#prev').click(function () {
    if ($('table td a.play').length > 0 && $('table td a.play').parents('tr').prev().length > 0) {
        $('table td a.play').removeClass('play').parents('tr').prev().find('a').addClass('play');
    } else {
        $('table td a.play').removeClass('play');
        $('table td').last().find('a').addClass('play');
    }
});
```